# how to get columns with value in CSV parser python

Tags: python, django

Another question in CSV parser. 
I  need to populate  year and its corresponding country to a table in a sqlite database. I have successfully narrowed it down to get me the values of all rows if any of them has a value  . But trying to save() the data to database, it throws `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''` for those without any value.

```
if (row[12] or row[13] or row[14] or row[15] ) != "":
                    country1 = re.match(r'.*\((\w+)\)', header[12])
                    country2 = re.match(r'.*\((\w+)\)', header[13])
                    country3 = re.match(r'.*\((\w+)\)', header[14])
                    country4 = re.match(r'.*\((\w+)\)', header[15])
                    Yr.country = country1 
                    Yr.country = country2 
                    Yr.country = country3 
                    Yr.country = country4 
                    Yr.mol = MoleculeDictionary.objects.get(id=row[0])
                    Yr.year = row[12]
                    Yr.year = row[13]
                    Yr.year = row[14]
                    Yr.year = row[15]
                    #Yr.save()
                    print country1.group(1), row[12], country2.group(1), row[13], country3.group(1), row[14], country4.group(1), row[15]




Year (US),Year (Eur),Year (Jap), Yea(CHI),
    ,,,,,
    ,,,,,
    ,,,,,
    ,,2009,,,
    ,,1977,,,
    ,1982,1983,,,
```

Print statement prints

```
US  Eur 2009 Jap  CHI 
US  Eur 1977 Jap  CHI 
US 1982 Eur 1983 Jap  CHI
```

But I would rather like to get only the columns with values in each row.How should I get just the EUR 2009 , EUR 1977, US 1982, EUR 1983. Please ignore my incompetence as I am new to python and Django.Thanks for all the suggestions in advance.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by

> would rather like to get only the columns with values in each row

so maybe you could specify your desired output?

However, given your csv as `test.csv`, this script

```
import csv

with open('test.csv') as myfile:
    reader = csv.reader(myfile)
    header = []
    for row in reader:
        if header == []: # first row
            header = row
        else:
            for i in range(len(row)):
                if row[i] != '':
                    # calculate custom header
                    custom_header = header[i].split('(')[1].split(')')[0].upper()
                    print custom_header, row[i]
```

will print

```
JAP 2009
JAP 1977
EUR 1982
JAP 1983
```

Is this what you want?